# JPA/Criteria Like percent character

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, criteria-api

I am trying to build dynamic query (with like condition). When I try it with raw sql into the mysql , it worked very well. Here is an example:

```
select * from dbiwant.want_activity m where m.want like "%bike%"
```

Then,  I've tried it with the CriteriaBuilder but I couldn't achieve to get the same results in Java. Just empty result. Here is my code:

```
Specifications specifications = Specifications.where(specificationService.isLike("want", search));


public Specification<WantActivity> isLike(String param, String search) {
        return new Specification<WantActivity>() {
            public javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate toPredicate(Root<WantActivity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                                                                    CriteriaBuilder builder) {
                return builder.like(root.get(param) ,"%" + search + "%");
            }
        };
}
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public Specification<WantActivity> isLike(String param, String search) {
    return new Specification<WantActivity>() {
        public javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate toPredicate(Root<WantActivity> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                                                                CriteriaBuilder builder) {

final Predicate like = query.where(builder.like(root.<String> get(param), search)).getRestriction();
return like;
        }
    };
```

Comment: See this may be help you:https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/